# Knockout dynamic control creation

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have 2 dropdown select box, first selection will change the options for second selection. I am using knockout to control it and it is working fine.

My second requirement is allow user to dynamic add the select box pair (add first and second select box together, first select box control the second select box).

Here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/mang/pyh9m7de/2/ which is working fine for the first time.
When user click on add new select box, i have no idea how to use knockout to solve my problem.

```
     <section class="col-sm-4 col-lg-5 selectContainer">
       <select class="form-control" data-bind="options: optionsSelection, value: selectedOption"></select>
     </section>
     <section class="col-sm-5">
       <select class="form-control" data-bind="options: colors"></select>
     </section>
     <section>
         <span class="input-group-btn">
         <button id="add" class="btn btn-success btn-add" type="button">
                                    add
         </button>
         </span>
    </section>
```

Comment: Can you describe the desired behavior in more detail?

Comment: You can click on my link to the code, then you will understand better. When you chnage the first selection, value = 1 or 2, then second selection will be changed as well. However, when you click on add button to add duplicated set of the control, i have no idea how to make the duplicated set of control work like original set of control by using knockout

Comment: mixing jquery with ko is not advisable until there is a definite need . cheers

Comment: Hi @supercool can you suggest what is the alternative solution? This is what i am able to think for now.

Comment: posted as answer please check and let me know . cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you should try something like this

**View :**

```
<div class="container" data-bind="foreach:array">
                <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <div class="entry input-group" style="margin-left:10em">
                        <section class="col-sm-4 col-lg-5 selectContainer">
                            <select class="form-control" data-bind="options: optionsSelection, value: selectedOption"></select>
                        </section>
                        <section class="col-sm-5">
                             <select class="form-control" data-bind="options: colors"></select>
                            </section>
                            <section>
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
```

Remove
                                    
                                    
                                
                            
                        
                    
                
          add

**ViewModel:**

```
function test(){
    var self=this;
self.selectedOption = ko.observable(0);
   self.allCategories = ko.observableArray([
    {type: 1, name: 'Red'},
    {type: 1, name: 'Blue'},
    {type: 1, name: 'Green'},
    {type: 2, name: 'xxx'},
    {type: 2, name: 'yyy'},
    {type: 2, name: 'zzz'}]); 

    self.optionsSelection = ko.observableArray([1,2]);

    self.colors = ko.computed(function () {
        var finalColors = [];
        var tempColors = ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.allCategories(), function (innerdata) {
            return innerdata.type == self.selectedOption();
        });
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(tempColors, function (item) {
            finalColors.push(item.name);
        });
        return finalColors;
    });
}


function MyViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.array=ko.observableArray([new test()]);
    self.add = function()
    { 
     self.array.push(new test());
    }
   self.remove=function(){
     self.array.remove(this);    
    }
}


$(document).ready(function () {
ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
})
```

sample working fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/pyh9m7de/4/)

Comment: oh thanks. But i need a remove button beside every newly added control, so that user can remove it anytime as well, is it possible?

Comment: Last question, i pormised. Now i want to add new container dynamically and each container allow me to add 2 select controller dynamic as your answer above. any good way to achieve this? Somehtng like copy and paste this container multiple time `<div class="container" data-bind="foreach:array">` and every container allow me to add and remove select controller.

Comment: i didn't get what you are referring to you want to keep the `foreach` on top of div container is it ? then try this http://jsfiddle.net/pyh9m7de/5/ .

Comment: I am refering to this example: http://jsfiddle.net/mang/XJPJZ/121/ User is able to add the tab dynamically and every tab content is different between each others. User can add/remove the control inside each tab separately. I hope i make my question more clear now.